# How to find same/mutual/common entries of two users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all pages two users like (`status = 1`) or dislike (`status = 0`).

Structure `pages_likes`:

[image]

Assume my user id (`uid`) is `1` and I'm on the page of user with user id `uid = 2`, I want to select all `page_id` entries I have in common with that user.

How could I select or just count the amount of all that `page_id` entries we have in common?

Comment: And you have tried WHAT before asking here for help?

Comment: Sample data and expected result will be more helpful.

Comment: I tried using `select union` or self join the same table, but I can't figure out the right way to do it or where to start correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a way to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.title_de, l.page_id
FROM
    (SELECT page_id
    FROM pages_likes
    WHERE uid in (2, 1) AND status = 1) l
LEFT JOIN pages p ON l.page_id = p.id
GROUP BY l.page_id
HAVING COUNT(l.page_id) > 1
```

I'm not sure if its the best way, because I would use this query twice with different WHERE-conditions (changing `status = 0` for dislikes), but this seems to work.